# How do I implement a backpropagation neural network with particle swarm optimization for rssi-based distance model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, implementation

I was trying to implement pso-bpnn. Can any one help with this?

I am unable to understand how a bpnn computes distance from rssi values. And how to optimize bpnn weights using pso.

Comment: Do you have any answers for your question?